# Angular 2 Update: no gui update after async data input

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I'm working with Angular2-Beta1,

but the templating from the "*ngFor" will not work and is only shown as 
`<!--template bindings={}-->`
and not as
`<template ...></template>`
as it is described here [angular2 on git - doc](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/core/01_templates.md)

The problem is also that I work here with electron and typescript and that I'm translating everything with webpack to "es5".

I got to the problem because of the async-data-input throw the node-process and they don't want to show up on the GUI but I can see them in the console.

My current typescript-file with the problem

```
import {Component, View, NgZone} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-material/all';
const electron = require('electron');
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

interface Result {
  videoId: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  channel: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'resultlist'
})
@View({
  directives: [MATERIAL_DIRECTIVES, NgFor],
  template: `
<div 
  style="height: 250px;">
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item class="md-2-line" *ngFor="#result of resultlistcontent; #i = index">
      <img [src]="result.thumbnail" class="md-avatar" alt="{{result.videoId}}"/>
      <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
        <h3> {{ result.title }} </h3>
        <p> {{ result.channel }}
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</div>
  `
})

export class Resultlist { 

  private resultlistcontent = RESULTLIST;
  private _ngZone:NgZone;

  constructor(zone:NgZone) {
    this._ngZone = zone;
    this._ngZone.run(() => {
      ipc.on('search-result', function (event, arg) {
      this.resultlistcontent = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < arg.pageInfo.resultsPerPage; i ++) {
        var tmpid = arg.items[i].id;
        var tmpsnip = arg.items[i].snippet;
        this.resultlistcontent.push( { videoId: tmpid.videoId, 
                            title: tmpsnip.title, 
                            thumbnail: tmpsnip.thumbnails.default.url, 
                            channel: tmpsnip.channelTitle});
      }
      console.log(this.resultlistcontent);
      })
    })
  }
}

var RESULTLIST: Result[] = [{videoId: '', title: 'Resultlist...', thumbnail: '', channel: 'test'},
  {videoId: "ZTVNgzvxoV0", title: "The Best Of Vocal Deep House Chill Out Music 2015", thumbnail: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZTVNgzvxoV0/default.jpg", channel: 'test'}];
```

Comment: Does it work with the data from the `RESULT_LIST`, without the code in the constructor?

Comment: Hi, yes the data from the 'RESULTLIST' are shown on the gui

Comment: Then it obviously isn't related to the template tag, only to change detection. I don't know this well enough myself yet to be able to help though. You might increase the chance for assistance by changing the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: yes - but after starting the application there is no ngFor more in the html <md-list-item class="md-2-line" role="listitem">...</md-list-item> and the NgZone is for async-data-input to check if there were a change and then to trigger a event.
I will try it with a service.

Comment: I don't know why you think there should. Template is a placeholder for HTML to be generated, when it's generated the template isn't needed anymore. `<!--template bindings={}-->` is an anchor for Angular to know where generated content was inserted and where it needs to be updated when bound data changes. What do you need `<template>` for in processed output?

Comment: thanks to Günther Zöchbauer: The problem was with the update of the bound data in the gui. The solution was: created a service which gets the data from the ipc-service. Then by subscribing the component to the service with the emitter it gets the data from the service in a NgZone (for async-data).

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I fixed using ngOnInit method https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this constructor... works for me:

```
constructor(zone: NgZone) {
        this._ngZone = zone;
        ipc.on('search-result', function (event, arg) {
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
                this.resultlistcontent = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < arg.pageInfo.resultsPerPage; i++) {
                    var tmpid = arg.items[i].id;
                    var tmpsnip = arg.items[i].snippet;
                    this.resultlistcontent.push({
                        videoId: tmpid.videoId,
                        title: tmpsnip.title,
                        thumbnail: tmpsnip.thumbnails.default.url,
                        channel: tmpsnip.channelTitle
                    });
                }
                console.log(this.resultlistcontent);
            });
        });
    }
```